# ColumnIndex and DisplayIndex Datagrid View

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, mapping

Hey I am trying to change the Column index of my dvg when I change the Displayindex using  the Allowusertoordercolumns property but when I move the columns I can't get it to change the Column Index.

I am getting an error that says the Column index is Read only .. is there anyway around this. ere is what I have got so far

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnDisplayIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewColumnEventArgs) _
 Handles DataGridView1.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged

    Dim messageBoxVB As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    messageBoxVB.AppendFormat("{0} = {1}", "Column", e.Column)
    messageBoxVB.AppendLine()
    '   MessageBox.Show(messageBoxVB.ToString(), "ColumnDisplayIndexChanged Event")

    If DataGridView1.Columns(e.Column.Name).Index <> e.Column.DisplayIndex Then
        DataGridView1.Columns(e.Column.Name).Index = (e.Column.DisplayIndex)
    End If
    'DataGridView1 = DataGridView1
End Sub
```

**BUTTON**

This is as far as I have got with the mapping button nothing to what i want just now

```
    Dim nbColumnsToTransfer As Integer = DataGridView2.Columns.GetColumnCount(1)

    Dim indexes As List(Of Integer) = (From column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)() _
                                          Take nbColumnsToTransfer _
                                          Order By column.DisplayIndex _
                                          Select column.Index).ToList()


    For c As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2

        Dim RNUM1 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(0)).Value)
        Dim RNUM2 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(1)).Value)
        If chkContactSplitReq.Checked = True Then

            If IsDBNull(DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(2)).Value) Then


                Dim RNUM3 As String = ""
                Dim RNUM4 As String = ""
                Dim RNUM5 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(5)).Value)
                Dim RNUM6 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(6)).Value)
                Dim RNUM7 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(7)).Value)

                DataGridView2.Rows.Add(RNUM1, RNUM2, RNUM3, RNUM4, RNUM5, RNUM6, RNUM7)

            Else

                Dim tempString As String = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(2)).Value)
                Dim Split() As String = tempString.Split(" "c)
                Dim RNUM3 As String = Split(0)
                If Split.Length > 1 Then
                    Dim RNUM4 As String = Split(1)
                    Dim RNUM5 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(4)).Value)
                    Dim RNUM6 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(5)).Value)
                    Dim RNUM7 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(6)).Value)

                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add(RNUM1, RNUM2, RNUM3, RNUM4, RNUM5, RNUM6, RNUM7)
                Else
                    Dim RNUM4 As String = ""
                    Dim RNUM5 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(4)).Value)
                    Dim RNUM6 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(5)).Value)
                    Dim RNUM7 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(6)).Value)

                    DataGridView2.Rows.Add(RNUM1, RNUM2, RNUM3, RNUM4, RNUM5, RNUM6, RNUM7)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Dim RNUM3 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(2)).Value)
            Dim RNUM4 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(3)).Value)
            Dim RNUM5 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(4)).Value)
            Dim RNUM6 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(5)).Value)
            Dim RNUM7 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(6)).Value)

            DataGridView2.Rows.Add(RNUM1, RNUM2, RNUM3, RNUM4, RNUM5, RNUM6, RNUM7)
        End If
```

Comment: No you can not change a DataGridView's column index. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewband.index(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find and interesting remark: "The value of this property does not necessarily correspond to the current visual position of the band within the collection. For example, if the user reorders columns in a DataGridView at run time (assuming the AllowUserToOrderColumns property is set to true), the value of the Index property of each column will not change. Instead, the column DisplayIndex values change. Sorting rows, however, does change their Index values."

Comment: See I am trying to map two different dgv,  am loading data from an excel spreed sheet into one then changing the position of the columns to match that of the second datagridview and then transfer the data. As the newly added table is going to be different every time and possible different headers eh "Company" and "CompanyName" I have not been sure how to do this

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is your second DataGridView a clone from the first?

Comment: is it a clone of some of the columns. Some from the first dgv should not be brought threw.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood well what you want to do, you could do it like this to load the data from your first DataGridView to your second:

```
DataGridView2.Rows.Clear()
For i As Integer = 0 to DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Datagridview2.Rows.Add(Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells("FirstColumn").Value, Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells("SecondColumn").Value, Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells("ThirdColumn").Value)
    ' or
    ' Datagridview2.Rows.Add(Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value, Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value, Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value)
Next
```

This way, you don't have to reorder your second DataGridView's columns, unless you want to. Anyways, one thing's sure, the index property of a DataGridViewColumn is Read Only so you can't do it the way you wanted to.

**Edit**

If you don't mind using a little Linq, you could do something like this. You can also do it without Linq, but here's the idea:

```
Dim NbOfSecondGridviewColumns As Integer = 3    
Dim indexes As List(Of Integer) = (From column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)() _
                                   Take NbOfSecondGridviewColumns _
                                   Order By column.DisplayIndex _
                                   Select column.Index).ToList()

For i As Integer = 0 to DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Datagridview2.Rows.Add(Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells(indexes(0)).Value, Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells(indexes(1)).Value, Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells(indexes(2)).Value)
Next
```

**Edit 2**

Here is what I would do in your button code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim nbColumnsToTransfer As Integer = DataGridView2.Columns.GetColumnCount(1)

    ' Get the indexes of the first [nbColumnsToTransfer] columns, ordered by their 
    ' display index, because your columns to be transferred are the first displayed
    Dim indexes As List(Of Integer) = (From column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)() _
                                       Take nbColumnsToTransfer _
                                       Order By column.DisplayIndex _
                                       Select column.Index).ToList()

    For c As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1

        ' Dim RNUM1 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(0).Value) => this won't work 
        ' because cells takes a column index value or column name in parameter. Don't 
        ' forget your columns displayed index ≠ your columns index,
        ' that's why I used the linq query above
        Dim RNUM1 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(0)).Value)
        Dim RNUM2 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(1)).Value)
        Dim RNUM3 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(2)).Value)
        Dim RNUM4 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(3)).Value)
        Dim RNUM5 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(4)).Value)
        Dim RNUM6 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(5)).Value)
        Dim RNUM7 = (DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(indexes(6)).Value)

        DataGridView2.Rows.Add(RNUM2, RNUM4, RNUM3, RNUM3, RNUM6, RNUM5, RNUM4)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: see  the header name is going change slightly with each spreadsheet loaded say "Company name" ... a different spread sheet may have just "Company" so i cant do this by header name. Is that the way you have suggested? would there possible be some other way around this problem

Comment: Then do it by column index. Instead of `Cells("FirstColumn")` you can easily do `Cells(0)`, for example. If there's anything else I didn't take into consideration, don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: yeah ive thought about this but also they can be in different orders when loading so ... thats why i have been using Allowusertoordercolumns as true to order them and to try and somehow using the displayindex to change the column index

Comment: Ok, you could get the column index from the column displayed index. See my edit.

Comment: I cant seem to get this to work correctly ... Is what your doing here is getting the coloum index  from the display index? I am getting an error saying the coloum,DisplayIndex is out of reach or not declared.. I am trying to run the mapping from a button now once all the columns have been reorganized

Comment: Actually what this query does is get the column indexes of the first displayed columns. My logic here is that you reordered the first datagridview columns, so that its first displayed columns correspond to the second datagridview's column. If this is what you're doing, post your button's click code so I can help you further.

Comment: its this line  Order By column.DisplayIndex).ToList() im having the problemwith it is saying column not declared or is not in scope

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, after the select clause, column is no longer in scope indeed. Move the order by before the select. See edit.

Comment: yes this is perfect also added a split into it aswell as one of the columns contains contact name which sometimes will come as first and second name but others just in one column :d thanks for the help @bishopBarber